# App for computing digits of e in c

Tags: c, algorithm, math

Can anyone explain how this code for computing of *e* works? Looks very easy for such complicated task, but I can't even understand the process. It has been created by Xavier Gourdon in 1999.

```
int main() {

  int N = 9009, a[9009], x = 0;
  for (int n = N - 1; n > 0; --n) {
      a[n] = 1;
  }
  a[1] = 2, a[0] = 0;
  while (N > 9) {
      int n = N--;
      while (--n) {
          a[n] = x % n;
          x = 10 * a[n-1] + x/n;
      }
      printf("%d", x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I traced the algorithm back to a 1995 paper by [Stanley Rabinowitz and Stan Wagon](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975006). It's quite interesting.

A bit of background first. Start with the ordinary decimal representation of *e*:

> *e* = 2.718281828...

This can be expressed as an infinite sum as follows:

> *e* = **2** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**7** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**8** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**2** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**8** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>(**1** ...

Obviously this isn't a particularly useful representation; we just have the same digits of *e* wrapped up inside a complicated expression.

But look what happens when we replace these <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub> factors with the reciprocals of the natural numbers:

> *e* = **2** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>6</sub>(**1** + <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>7</sub>(**1** ...

This so-called *mixed-radix* representation gives us a sequence consisting of the digit 2 followed by a repeating sequence of 1's. It's easy to see why this works. When we expand the brackets, we end up with the well-known Taylor series for e:

> *e* = 1 + 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + 1/5! + 1/6! + 1/7! + ...

So how does this algorithm work? Well, we start by filling an array with the mixed-radix number (0; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; ...). To generate each successive digit, we simply multiply this number by 10 and spit out the leftmost digit.*

But since the number is represented in mixed-radix form, we have to work in a different base at each digit. To do this, we work from right to left, multiplying the *n*th digit by 10 and replacing it with the resulting value modulo *n*. If the result was greater than or equal to *n*, we carry the value *x*/*n* to the next digit to the left. (Dividing by *n* changes the base from 1/n! to 1/(n-1)!, which is what we want). This is effectively what the inner loop does:

```
  while (--n) {
      a[n] = x % n;
      x = 10 * a[n-1] + x/n;
  }
```

Here, *x* is initialized to zero at the start of the program, and the initial 0 at the start of the array ensures that it is reset to zero every time the inner loop finishes. As a result, the array will gradually fill with zeroes from the right as the program runs. This is why *n* can be initialized with the decreasing value *N*-- at each step of the outer loop.

The additional 9 digits at the end of the array are presumably included to safeguard against rounding errors. When this code is run, *x* reaches a maximum value of 89671, which means the quotients will be carried across multiple digits.

#### Notes:

1. This is a type of [spigot algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm), because it outputs successive digits of *e* using simple integer arithmetic.
2. As noted by Rabinowitz and Wagon in their paper, [this algorithm was actually invented 50 years ago by A.H.J. Sale](https://eprints.utas.edu.au/121/1/Calculation_of_e.pdf)

---

<sup>* Except at the first iteration where it outputs two digits ("27")</sup>

Comment: [Here's a direct link to the paper by Rabinowitz and Wagon](http://web.archive.org/web/20120202121628/www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf)